Getting 'Operation Timeout' error while connecting to hidden network via DBus, but able to connect using connmanctl
I am trying to connect to a hidden Wi-Fi network using Connman in my Qt project via DBus.
I am able to connect to non-hidden networks without any issue, but when trying to connect to a hidden network, I get the Operation Timeout error. I haven't been able to resolve this.
Here is the DBus code (Connman Agent) I am trying to use:
QVariantMap ConnmanAgent::RequestInput(QDBusObjectPath path, QMap<QString, QVariant> dict) 
{ Q_UNUSED(path)

QVariantMap inputMap;
inputMap["Name"] = QLatin1String("HiddenSSID");
inputMap["SSID"] = QLatin1String("HiddenSSID");
inputMap["Passphrase"] = QLatin1String("123456789xy");
inputMap["Hidden"] = true;

return inputMap;
}

I have tried to connect to a hidden Wi-Fi network via DBus by configuring the SSID, Passphrase, and Hidden parameters correctly. The code I used attempts to set these values in a QVariantMap and then call the appropriate DBus methods. I also tested the connection using connmanctl from the command line, which worked without any issues, so I expected the DBus method to work the same way.
However, when trying to connect through DBus, I encounter an Operation Timeout error. I expected the connection to be established successfully, similar to how it works with connmanctl, without timing out.
I believe I am setting the SSID and Passphrase correctly. However, when trying to connect via DBus, I get the Operation Timeout error. On the other hand, I can connect successfully using connmanctl from the command line.
Steps of what I’ve done so far:

I used the correct service path (/net/connman/service/wifi_hidden).
I set the Hidden parameter to true.
I made sure to send the necessary configuration to Connman.
The network I am trying to connect to is a hidden Wi-Fi network.
I can connect to the network using connmanctl without any issues.
Connecting to other (non-hidden) networks works fine via DBus.

Despite this, I am still unable to connect. How can I fix this issue? Additional question: How can I get more detailed error messages from DBus during the connection attempt?
